# serverless framework deploy lambda from zip file

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, aws-lambda, serverless

i have a lambda function as a zip file and i want to use serverless framework to upload this zip file. The server less function creates a eventsbridge and triggers a lambda function. The below serverless code works for lambda function but not for zip file.

```
  lambdaForSecurityHub:
    name: securityhub-forwarder
    role: SecurityHubLambdaRole
    handler: functions/xxxxxxxxxx.lambda_handler
    events:
      - eventBridge:
          eventBus: ${self:custom.securityhubEventBusArn}
          name: securityhub-findings-resolver-rule
          pattern:
            source:
              - aws.ec2
              - aws.iam
              - aws.s3
            detail-type:
              - AWS API Call via CloudTrail
            detail:
              eventSource:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
                - iam.amazonaws.com
                - s3.amazonaws.com
              eventName:
                - TerminateInstances
                - DeleteRole
                - DeleteBucket
                - DeleteSecurityGroup
```

Any help?